# First font in font-family doesn't apply as long as there is alternative

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

The website is https://christopherjohnrogers.com/ (I don't work there, it's just a school project). I'm on Win Chrome.

```
font-family: Sneak,-apple-system,sans-serif;
```

So, Sneak loads, but is not applied, I just see the default Chrome sans-serif. As soon as I start removing either `-apple-system` or `sans-serif` in DevTools, it gets applied immediately.

Does it jump to secondary fonts because Sneak takes too much time to load (1.7s)? And if I delete `-apple-system`, could it jump to the first option, because it re-renders every time I edit CSS?

I would expect automatic rerendering once the font loads, but apparently, this is not happening. Why? And how would you make this work? Thanks!

PS And is `system-ui` preferable to `-apple-system` these days?

---

Info Log on Console (From Firefox 90):

```
downloadable font: font-display timeout, webfont not used (font-family: "Sneak" style:normal weight:500 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/3374/4540/files/Sneak-Medium.woff2
downloadable font: font-display timeout, webfont not used (font-family: "Sneak" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/3374/4540/files/Sneak-Regular.woff2
```

UPD Thanks for edit, @Amith!

AFAIK the default timeout for Chrome is 3 s, why is it exceeded with 1.7 s? I don't see any `font-display` timeout set up manually.

Comment: Post your CSS @font-face settings in the question.

Comment: There are none that I see, just font-family. But maybe @font-face should be used instead? Again, this is a publically available website that I'm analyzing with Google DevTools.

Comment: Sure. They're "your CSS" in the sense that they are the subject of your enquiry. You'll find the @font-face settings at the top of the stylesheet. They're used in conjunction with the font-family, not instead of.

Comment: `font-display: optional` in https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0474/3374/4540/t/4/assets/theme.scss.css?v=3033443777675231066 L1:C279

Comment: Of course, @Alohci! I meant, you probably can see better than me - because I don't see @font-face anywhere on Styles. Is it me, or should I use Firefox tools instead of Chrome?

Comment: Thank you, @Kaiido - does it mean the issue is wherever the font is downloaded from, not in the website CSS? Is there a way to override this?

Comment: The css file I linked to is where the issue is, at Line 1, Column 279, and this is part of that website CSS.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Kaiido, I don't know how to open the file in a readable format (lines and columns, not just screens of text), what tool should I use? Visual Studio Code doesn't help, I don't know any other tools unfortunately. Thank you so much!

Comment: UPD Installed Firefox, now can see CSS clearly! Thank you!